# What is the quotient of a quotient module?

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, quotient-group

Say you have $N=M\big/K$, where $M$ is an $R$-module and $K$ lies inside $M$. When I take $N\big/IN$, with $I$ being an ideal in $R$, is that equal to $$M\big/\big(IM + K)\ ?$$ How do you find that out ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$N/IN=\frac{M/K}{I(M/K)}=\frac{M/K}{(IM+K)/K}\cong\frac{M}{IM+K}$

The first equality is just unpacking the notation you chose to eliminate $N$.

The second equality computes $I(M/K)$, which by definition must be of the form $A/K$ where $A$ contains $IM$ and $K$, and the submodule that fits the bill then is $IM+K$.

The isomorphism is simply the "third isomorphism theorem."

Perhaps you should not say that it is *equal to* because as sets they are not equal. But they are the same up to isomorphism of modules, if that is what you want.